# One of the ones - singular or plural?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, difference, singular-vs-plural

Should the singular or plural be used after one of the ones?

> You're one of the ones that understand(s) me

I've seen a native speaker use the singular form (which likely makes it at least acceptable), but shouldn't it be plural? The verb applies to multiple people, you being one of which.

Answer (score 1):

> You're one of the ones that understand(s) me

The native speaker was probably hypercorrecting. Note: I prefer "who".

A paraphrase should make it clear.

*Of the ones who understand me, you're one.*

We could expand it more

*There are some 'ones' who understand me, and you are one of those ones.*

Comment: Interestingly, Google Books has more hits for the exact text [*I'm one of the few that **do***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%27m+one+of+the+few+that+do%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk03ZRgKTq9FXjEP-MXpThAOb3Usstw:1609760515975&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYlemdmYLuAhVOZcAKHWXxBEsQpwUIJg&biw=1300&bih=703&dpr=1.25) than [*I'm one of the few that **does***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%27m+one+of+the+few+that+does%22&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk03LjlSaIh_qFnkQRQ96nRbtqG4img:1609760527918&source=lnt&tbs=sbd:1&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj9lMKjmYLuAhW1lFwKHSD8BrIQpwUIJg&biw=1300&bih=703&dpr=1.25).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica - Thanks,  that's useful evidence in favour of what I say.

Comment: I can't say I feel that strongly about it myself. Unless it was being asked about here, I probably wouldn't notice the "incorrect" version (especially in spoken contexts). But I would just flag up 1: [*He is one of the boys who **play** football = There are some boys who play football, and he is one of them.*](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/200213/2637)
As opposed to *He is one of the boys who **plays** football = There are some boys, and he is one of them that happens to play football.*

Comment: ...in which context there's probably been a lot written about "proximity agreement" in English. Much of it based on pedantic logic and "Latin" grammar rather than recording / analysing what people actually say.